# Copy constructor and dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I will keep it short and clear - in order to practise dynamically allocated memory, I decided to make a circle in which I will store it's parameters (X and Y of the center and radius length) in a dynamically allocated array. Since the array is dynamically allocated this means that in order to stop a leak I have to implement a constructor. It also means that in order to avoid a couple of other bugs I need to implement a copy constructor and overload the assignment operator. (with pretty much the same code) I think I have implemented the destructor reasonably well. I do need a bit of help with the copy constructor, though.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Circle
{
private:
    int* data;
public:
    Circle(){
        cout <<"I am the default constructor" << endl;
        data = NULL;
    }
    Circle(int* p){
        cout <<"I am the set up constructor" << endl;
        data = p;
    }
    ~Circle(){
        cout <<"I am the destructor" << endl;
        delete data;
    }
    Circle& operator=(const Circle& tt1){
        cout << "Overloaded assignment operator reporting in!" << endl;
        if(this != &tt1){
            //free old data
            delete this->data;
            data = new int(3);
           *data = *(tt1.get_data());
            *(arr+1) = *(tt1->get_data()+1);
            *(arr+2) = *(tt1->get_data()+2);
            return *this;
        }
    }
    Circle(const Circle& tt1){
        cout << "I am the copy constructor!" << endl;
        if(this != &tt1){
            //free old data
            delete this->data;
            data = new int(3);
           *data = *(tt1.get_data());
            *(arr+1) = *(tt1->get_data()+1);
            *(arr+2) = *(tt1->get_data()+2);
            return *this;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    //is this object constructed well?
    int arr [] = { 16, 2, 7};
    Circle a(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remarks: 1) `new int(3)` doesn't do what you expect it to do (`data = new int[3]`). 2) For every `new[]` you need a `delete[]` (`delete[] data`). 3) `int arr[] = {1,2,3}; int * ptr = arr; delete[] ptr;` causes undefined behaviour (mnemonic trick: did you use `new[]`? If you didn't, ? `delete[]` will be wrong).

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Zeta: Where's the mnemonic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//is this object constructed well?
int arr [] = { 16, 2, 7};
Circle a(arr);
```

The answer is "yes and no": Your constructor does not make a copy of the array, it just copies a pointer to the first element of an array. So if you don't want your `Circle` class to own the array, you do not need to provide destructor, copy constructor or assignment operator.

But it is more likely that you *do* want your class to own the array, in which case you need to make a local copy of it and store it. For this to work, you need one extra piece of information: the size of the array, which is completely lost when passed to (and implement the destructor, copy constructor, assignment operator) a function taking a pointer.

**Edit** since this is an exercise in dynamic allocation in the case where the input array is always size 3, then this is an example of a constructor taking an array:

```
Circle(int* p)
{
  data = new int[3];
  std::copy(p, p+3, data); // UB if p doesn't point to an array of at least 3 elements
}
```

You need to call `delete[]` in the destructor, since you called `new[]`:

```
~Circle()
{
    delete [] data;
}
```

When implementing the assignment operator, consider the [copy and swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap).

Comment: Yes, I do want the class to own the array. Since I am always going to use exactly 3 elements, can I skip passing it ? Also, what would be a correct construction of an object that owns the array?

Comment: @Bloodcount if the size is always three, then you probably do not want dynamic allocation. So what are the real constraints?

Comment: I agree that it is bad design to do it with dynamic memory, however I am right now learning the usage of the copy constructor and even though this isn't a good example I want to see it working (my plan is to implement my own version of a vector a bit later, that is why I am using a dynamically allocated array)

Comment: @Bloodcount I added a constructor and a destructor. With the former, you can probably figure out the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: I think I can figure the rest out on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I write a right code about your practise, I hope this can help you. I build this by tdm-gcc and it run well.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm> //std::copy
using namespace std;

class Circle {
private:
 int* data;

public:
 Circle(){
  cout <<"I am the default constructor" << endl;
  data = NULL;
 }

 Circle(int* p){
  cout <<"I am the set up constructor" << endl;
  data =new int[3];
  copy(p,p+3,data);
 }

 ~Circle(){
  cout <<"I am the destructor" << endl;
  if (data!=NULL) {
   delete[] data;
  }
 }

 Circle(const Circle& tt1){
  cout << "I am the copy constructor!" << endl;
  if (this != &tt1) {
   if (data!=NULL) {
    delete[] data;
   }

   data = new int[3];
   *data = *(tt1.get_data());
   *(data+1) = *(tt1.get_data()+1);
   *(data+2) = *(tt1.get_data()+2);
  }
 }

 Circle& operator=(const Circle& tt1){
  cout << "Overloaded assignment operator reporting in!" << endl;
  if (this != &tt1) {
   if (data!=NULL) {
    delete[] data;
   }
   data = new int[3];
   *data = *(tt1.get_data());
   *(data+1) = *(tt1.get_data()+1);
   *(data+2) = *(tt1.get_data()+2);
  }
 }

 int* get_data() const {
  return data;
 }
};

int main(){
 int arr[]={16,2,7};
 Circle a(arr);
 cout<<*a.get_data()<<'\t'
 <<*(a.get_data()+1)<<'\t'
 <<*(a.get_data()+2)<<endl<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: Not necessary to check pointer for `NULL` before deleting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you say is correct. But thank you very much.

Comment: It is. You could read about it in § 5.3.5 (2, 6, 7) C++ Standard

Comment: There is no need to check for self-assignment in a copy constructor, it is debatable whether it is a good idea in an assignment operator (it can silently hide buggy code), there is no need for `get_data`, and you can use `std::copy` to copy the elements of one `Circle` to the other.

Comment: `get_data` is redundant, but this is just a practice, use many ways I think is godd, are you agree me?  Thank you for your advice. @juanchopanza